# Google Spreadsheet API вставляет значение с кавычкой '

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

```
$values = [];

$cellData = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellData();
$value = new Google_Service_Sheets_ExtendedValue();

$value->setStringValue($aDateS->format("d.m.Y")); // $aDateS -> DateTime object
$cellData->setUserEnteredValue($value);    
$values[] = $cellData;

$rowData = new Google_Service_Sheets_RowData();
$rowData->setValues($values);
$rows[] = $rowData;
```

Далее я создаю запрос:

```
$appendRequest->setSheetId($aSheetId);
$appendRequest->setRows($rowAr);
$appendRequest->setFields("userEnteredValue");

$request = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$request->setAppendCells($appendRequest);

$requests = [$request];

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(["requests" => $requests]);
```

И отправляю, он успешно отправляется, но перед самой датой он почему то вставляет 'кавычку
[image: Скрин проблемы]

Другие значения нормально вставляются.

Answer (score 0):

Удалить кавычку конца строки

```
rtrim($date, "'");
```

Удалить кавычку с начала строка

```
ltrim($date, "'");
```

Comment: В это то и проблема, что сам запрос передается без 'кавычки, это гугл уже что-то мудрит, либо я что-то не понимаю. Смотрел под снифером запрос проходит без этой кавычки

Comment: У MSSQL, для передачи кириллицы передается формат такого значения в формате `N'значение`. У вас все строковые значения так добавляются?